# .NET Library for programmatically generating SQL objects

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net, create-table

I am looking for a .NET library for programmatically generating tables, stored procedures, views and relationships against an SQL 2008 database.  Other than raw ADO.NET, what are my options?

Comment: This is a really generic thing to ask for and I'm not sure what a "library" might offer you over just passing the commands through ado.net would be.  What, exactly, are you looking for a library to do?

Comment: What would it create it from? User input, an ERD, class structures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) comes with SQL Server out of the box.

Comment: A good answer, but I think he's looking more for an ORM that includes table generation.

Comment: Really? I'm not sure, Chris Lively already asked him to make his question more clear. And at this moment, both other answers (which both suggest ORMs) have been voted down (and I didn't do it :-)

Comment: And, I mean...of course ORMs can create tables and stuff, but I don't know of an ORM that creates sprocs. And as far as I know, most ORMs can create a database once from scratch. But when it's already existing and full of data, is it really possible to tell an ORM, for example "leave the whole database as it is, but add one new table and one new view"? I have only worked with Nhibernate so far and I never tried to use the "create database" stuff, because I work with existing databases all the time.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell what you're asking so I'll answer as best I can given the information I've got.

Personally I'd go with an object-relational mapping framework such as [NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/).

This will create an environment for you that makes it easy to work with your database in an abstracted way, affording you more time to focus on the other portions of your application.

To answer your question on creating database tables etc, [DataObjects.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataObjects.NET) seems to offer something that sounds like it fits with what you want.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, you are looking some king of ORM...
Here are some links

WCF RIA Services:  http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

NHibernate:   http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET

Also there are numerous commercial products,offering such functionality.

Comment: Which of those will actually create stored procs, database relationships and/or tables...  You know, things the OP asked for.

Comment: OK,creating database objects is not that ORM is expected to do :-) I guess the question is not clear enough.